How to debug and fix Entra ID MFA auth in SQL Server Management Studio
SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 19.0 onwards supports Entra ID MFA authentication which delegates user authentication to, guess what, Entra ID.
This works well, however, today the successful return token is ending up in the browser instead of posting back to SSMS. SSMS gets locked for ever waiting for the response.
Any ideas on how to diagnose and fix it?
Thanks in advance to anyone who shares their knowledge

This was just a browser cache issue. Clearing the cache resolved this issue. Writing it here because for a while it was very confusing and browser problem was not the first suspicion.
